# Liquibase generateChangeLog Failed: Java heap space

Tags: java, heap-memory, liquibase

When I try to generate SQL data from a DB2 database, I am getting Java Heap space issue. There are around 25 tables with approx 1000 records.

I use the below scripts in generating the changeset data:

```
C:\liquibase-3.0.2-bin>liquibase --driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver \
--classpath="C:\db2jcc.jar" \
--changeLogFile="C:\Liquibase Release\liqui_MYDB_MYSCHEMA_Data.xml" \
--url="jdbc:db2://__ip__here__:9008/MYDB" \
--username="user" \
--password="12345" \
--defaultSchemaName="MYSCHEMA" \
--diffTypes=data  \
generateChangeLog
```

I tried to increase the memory by setting JAVA_OPTS in liquibase.bat file, but this did not yield any solution:

- `set JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"`
- `set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"`

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be running into MaxPermSize, so just setting a larger Xmx flag should be all that is needed.

It may also help to add the `--dataOutputDirectory=DIR_YOU_WANT` flag. That will cause Liquibase to output the data in CSV files which will be less mmemory intensive to create. The resulting XML+CSV is usually more manageable than a huge XML file as well

Something like:

```
C:\liquibase-3.0.2-bin>liquibase \ 
--driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver \ 
--classpat h="C:\db2jcc.jar" \ 
--changeLogFile="C:\Liquibase Release\liqui_MYDB_MYSCHEMA_Data.xml" \ 
--url="jdbc:db2://__ip__here__:9008/MYDB" \ 
--username="user" \ 
--password="12345" \ 
--defaultSchemaName="MYSCHEMA" \ 
--diffTypes=data \ 
--dataOutputDirectory=C:\Liquibase Release\liqui_MYDB_MYSCHEMA_Data.out \ 
generateChangeLog
```

Comment: I had the same issue but with a much bigger database and this was the perfect solution, the changelog has been generate in seconds

Answer (score 0):

also, you can call a jar file directly, in this case you can just add -Xmx2g property. -Xmx2g - 2 gigabytes of memory

in another words:

```
C:\liquibase-3.0.2-bin>java -Xmx2g -jar liquibase.jar \ 
--classpath h="C:\db2jcc.jar" \ 
--changeLogFile="C:\Liquibase Release\liqui_MYDB_MYSCHEMA_Data.xml" \ 
--url="jdbc:db2://__ip__here__:9008/MYDB" \ 
--username="user" \ 
--password="12345" \ 
--defaultSchemaName="MYSCHEMA" \ 
--diffTypes=data \ 
--dataOutputDirectory=C:\Liquibase Release\liqui_MYDB_MYSCHEMA_Data.out \ 
generateChangeLog
```

also you may get an error about database driver, so you should add something like --driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver (for oracle)